# Babelify error: no writecb in Transform class

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify, babeljs

I'm getting an error running a gulp task that nobody else in my dev group is getting, despite generally the same environment. I'm on OS X. Here's the gulp block:

```
gulp.task('transpile', function() {
    // http://problematic.io/2015/02/26/using-babel-and-browserify-with-gulp/
    // just pass in app.js and browserify will pull in dependencies
    return gulp.src(['./src/app.js'])
        .pipe(through2.obj(function(file, enc, next) {
            browserify(file.path, {debug: true})
                .transform(require('babelify'))
                .bundle(function(err, res) {
                    if (err) { return next(err); }
                    file.contents = res;
                    next(null, file);
                })
        }))
        .on('error', function(error) {
            console.log(error.stack);
            this.emit('end');
        })
        .pipe(gulp.dest(transpile_dest));
});
```

And here's the error:

```
Error: no writecb in Transform class
    at afterTransform (.../node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:75:33)
    at TransformState.afterTransform (.../node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:59:12)
    at Readable.<anonymous> (.../gulpfile.js:142:39)
    at Readable.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Labeled.<anonymous> (.../node_modules/read-only-stream/index.js:27:44)
    at Labeled.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Labeled.<anonymous> (.../node_modules/stream-splicer/index.js:133:18)
    at Labeled.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at Deps.<anonymous> (.../node_modules/stream-splicer/index.js:133:18)
    at Deps.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at .../node_modules/module-deps/index.js:345:30
    at onresolve (.../node_modules/module-deps/index.js:161:25)
    at .../node_modules/browserify/index.js:485:22
    at .../node_modules/browser-resolve/index.js:229:20
    at .../node_modules/browser-resolve/index.js:98:24
    at fs.js:207:20
```

(I've replaced the project root with ...)

I've checked that the files it's looking for exist, that they're owned and readable by me, and re-installed all my node modules and other dependencies from scratch. What else should I do or look for?

Comment: What version of nodejs are you using?

Comment: node v0.10.26, npm v3.3.10, gulp v 3.9.0,

Comment: Wiping out directories and reinstalling npm and gulp eventually fixed this for me. Ugh, what a terrible answer.